# How to consolidate these two MongoDB operations into one?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an operation in my controller for updating a user's "score" for a certain topic when they leave a review.

But right now it's two separate Mongo operations. One to delete the current score, and another to add the new score.

Is there any way to make this into one operation instead of two?

```
const userScoring = await User
        .findByIdAndUpdate(userId,
          { $pull: { scores: {_id: currentScore._id}}},
          { new: true }
        )
const userReScoring = await User
        .findByIdAndUpdate(userId,
          { $addToSet: { scores: {topic: t, score: (currentScore.score + 10)}}},
          { new: true }
        )
```

Comment: you can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), but any way you have to write a condition the operation is pull or  push, so i think  2 queries are more efficient and specially both are doing own operation.

Comment: Your update has two operations on array field(s). It might be possible to use update operation's _arrayFilters_ to perform the update in a single operation. I suggest you include a sample input document in your post.